# What's wrong with my solution of inequality?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

Question: solve the following inequality: $\frac{x}{2} \geq \frac{5}{x + 1} + 4$

My solution: $\frac{x}{2} - \frac{5}{x + 1} + 4 \geq 0$

$\implies \frac{x(x + 1) - 10(x + 1) - 8(x + 1)}{(x + 1) 2} \geq 0$

$\implies \frac{x^2 + x - 10x - 10 -8x -8}{(x + 1)2} \geq 0$

$\implies \frac{x^2 -17x -18}{(x + 1)2} \geq 0$

$\implies \frac{(x - 18)(x + 1)}{(x + 1)2} \geq 0$

$\implies \frac{(x - 18)}{2} \geq0$

$\implies x \geq 18$

Solution given in the site: [image: Solution]

My real question: what am I doing wrong?

Comment: $\frac{5}{x+1}\not=\frac{10(x+1)}{2(x+1)}$.

Comment: Incorrectly adding fractions in the first step.

Comment: Although it is not the main mistake here, canceling out is the most common mistake one can do in algebra. You shouldn't have canceled $(x+1)$ out without looking what they lead to.

Comment: Everyone: I'm soooo stupid! Thank you so much. Also, @E.Girgin, I can't cancel, really? I know why I shouldn't multiply, but I can't cancel like this? Why so?

Comment: You can cancel, it's just a warning to be careful when you're doing it. It really does not mean anything in this sense, as the value is not undefined for $x=-1$, but, for an inequality like $y(x+1)\le z(x+1)$, canceling $(x+1)$ means ignoring $x=-1$.

Comment: @user331377: Your cancelling is fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you compute $$\frac{x}{2} - \frac{5}{x + 1} - 4$$ you write the *numerator* to be $$x(x + 1) - 10\color{red}{(x + 1)} - 8(x + 1) .$$ The middle term is wrong, it should be only $-10$, because $\color{red}{x+1}$ is already present in the denominator of the middle fraction, so you don't have to multiply the middle fraction by it, but only by $2$. Therefore, the corrrect numerator is $$x(x + 1) - 10 - 8(x + 1) = x^2 -7x - 18 ,$$ exactly as in the correct version presented in the photograph.